# Using SelectArg in ormlite Having clause?

Tags: java, android, sql, ormlite, query-builder

I need to us a placeholder in the having clause of my query builder.
I tried using a "?" mark but then I get:
`java.sql.SQLException: argument holder index 1 not valid, only 1 in statement`

This is the thing I try to accomplish:

```
QueryBuilder<ArchiefTag, Integer> archiefTagQb = helper
        .getArchiefTagDao().queryBuilder();

tagSelectArg = new SelectArg(); 

archiefTagQb.where().in(ArchiefTag.TAG_FIELD, tagSelectArg);
archiefTagQb.groupBy(ArchiefTag.ARCHIEF_ENTRY_FIELD);

QueryBuilder<ArchiefEntry, Date> archiefEntryQb = helper
       .getArchiefEntryDao().queryBuilder();
archiefEntryQb.join(archiefTagQb);

//the having must be on the outer join query. Don't know why
archiefEntryQb.having(String.format("COUNT(%s) = ?",ArchiefTag.TAG_FIELD));

preparedGetArchiefForTags = archiefEntryQb.prepare();
```

The generated sql is:

```
SELECT `ARCHIEF_ENTRY`.* 
FROM `ARCHIEF_ENTRY` 
INNER JOIN `ARCHIEF_TAG` ON `ARCHIEF_ENTRY`.`id_entry` = `ARCHIEF_TAG`.`entry` 
GROUP BY `ARCHIEF_TAG`.`entry` 
HAVING COUNT(tag) = ?
```

But when I call:
`preparedGetArchiefForTags.setArgumentHolderValue(1, 3);`
The above Exception occurs.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> But when I call: preparedGetArchiefForTags.setArgumentHolderValue(1, 3); The above Exception.

If you take a look at the [javadocs for the `setArgumentHolderValue(...)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/PreparedStmt.html#setArgumentHolderValue%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29), the `index` argument should be 0 based and *not* 1 based like SQL.

To quote:

> index - The index of the holder you are going to set, 0 based. See NOTE above.

So your code should be:

```
preparedGetArchiefForTags.setArgumentHolderValue(0, 3);
```

I've tweaked the exception to make this more plain.

```
throw new SQLException("argument holder index " + index + " is not valid, only "
    + argHolders.length + " in statement (index starts at 0)");
```

Comment: still get an exception `java.sql.SQLException: argument holder index 0 not valid, only 0 in statement`

Comment: You used to have 1 in the statement so I think your query must have changed?  @Vrolijkx

Comment: nope the statement hasn't changed but i see at the moment that i forgot a piece in the generated sql. But i worked around the problem using executeRaw()